# How to enable developer mode on an iPhone or iPad ( iOS | iPadOS )?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ipados

I got an alert when tried to open one provisioned testing build on iOS 16.0.
Alert says -

> "Your App" required Developer Mode to run. Until Developer Mode has been
> enabled this app will not be available for use.

Comment: >>> iPhone Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Developer Mode -> turn ON Developer mode

Comment: where is it located? I can't find privacy & security on settings

Comment: @eskemender do get any other options

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**In Short**

> Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Developer Mode -> turn ON Developer mode

In some cases you may have to unplug iOS device from Mac and re-plug  it to see the "Developer Mode" option.

---

**In Depth**

In iOS 16.0 Apple have made turning Developer Mode On mandatory if you want to physically connect your device to Xcode on Mac.

When you attempt to build and run to the device, Xcode displays following alert to tell you the destination isn’t valid because Developer Mode is disabled.

[image]

**To Enable developer mode on iPhone**

Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Developer Mode -> turn ON Developer mode as follows :

1. In Settings app on iPhone, select Privacy & Security.

[image]

2. Scroll down to the Developer Mode. Turn on it.

[image]

3. After that, choose Restart from action sheet to restart your iPhone.

[image]

4. A pop-up window appears when the phone is rebooted. To enable developer mode, click "Turn On" again and then enter the device password.

Ref - [Apple Doc - Enabling Developer Mode on a device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device#:%7E:text=As%20indicated%20by%20the%20alert%2C%20to,and%20use%20the%20%E2%80%9CDeveloper%20Mode%E2%80%9D%20switch.)

Comment: I did not see the "Developer Mode" until I unplugged and plugged my iPad back into the Mac. You may have to do the same if you are not seeing the "Developer Mode" option. Maybe this is because my iPad was not unlocked when I plugged it into the Mac the first time?

Comment: I just upgraded my iPhone 12 mini to ios 16.1.1 and developer mode is no longer appearing on Settings -> Privacy & Security. According to some web sites, I can make it reappear as an option if I install something from some "mysterious" developer. Even plugging it into my MacBook Pro with Xcode running does not cause it to appear as an option.

Comment: Hi, I can't find the Privacy and Security option on my settings. Is there something I should do? It was only Privacy option and when I open that, there is no developer mode

Comment: Plugins your device to Mac with Xcode opened and you should be able to see this option.

Comment: I needed to re-pair my device as described in @AnilKumar's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74068281/480608

Comment: This one works for me: In some cases you may have to unplug iOS device from Mac and re-plug it to see the "Developer Mode" option.

Answer (score 60):

Looks like you're trying to run it on a physical device. On the iPhone, go to Settings > Privacy & Security on the iOS device -> Developer Mode -> toggle the Developer mode on.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device

Comment: Apple seems to try to hide this as every single iteration of their software they move that to another area in the settings.
On my iphone I can not find it in any of the "documented" locations.

Comment: I just upgraded my iPhone 12 mini to ios 16.1.1 and developer mode is no longer appearing on Settings -> Privacy & Security. According to some web sites, I can make it reappear as an option if I install something from some "mysterious" developer.

Comment: The option was not there for me while I had my iPhone plugged in. I had to unplug and re-open my settings for it to appear.

Comment: Refer below answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73918613/8238512

Answer (score 44):

If "Developer Mode" is not showing up at "Privacy & Security" try this:

> Turning on Developer Mode requires you to physically connect your device to a machine running Xcode. With a project open in Xcode 14 Beta 3, connect your phone and then navigate to Settings -> Privacy & Security, Developer Mode should appear now. If you've had that settings pane open before you connected your device, you may have to navigate back to Settings, and then go into Privacy & Security again.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710066

It worked to me.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I had my phone connected to my Mac with Xcode running but needed to unplug and plug it back in to get the Developer Mode option to show up

Comment: Thanks, worked for me as well. Had to restart the settings app though

Answer (score 23):

`Settings` -> `Privacy & Security` -> `Developer Mode` -> `turn ON Developer mode` >

But in my case i don't have that Developer mode option: If any one facing same issue.

Follow steps:
In xcode press Command + shft + 2 -> Unpair your device -> Prompt on your phone -> Tap on Trust . Go To above path and This time you will see developer option.

Cheers

Comment: Unpairing and repairing by tapping trust worked for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

To show Developer Mode (not showing in Privacy and Security on the iPhone) - with Xcode 14.2 running, physically connect, disconnect, and reconnect to your Mac. Then the Developer Mode option will show under Privacy and Security - follow the prompts on your phone and any in Xcode. See below for my configuration

Background: iPhone 14, iOS 16.1.2 did not show the Developer Mode under Privacy and Security. Some of the contributors said that you had to connect the iPhone to Xcode. Tried that and still no Developer Mode. A contributor said, "Your might have to connect, disconnect, and reconnect for the developer mode to show on the iPhone". For me this was the case and it worked. My configuration is Xcode 14.2 running on MacOS Ventura 13.2.

Comment: to be specific 
force close settings
connect to mac with xcode open
settings -> privacy security
enable developer mode

Answer (score 3):

- Open Xcode on your Mac
- Open a project on Xcode
- Connect your iPhone and Mac while keeping the project on Xcode running
- Go to Settings > Privacy and Security, Developer Mode appears

Answer (score 2):

The solution Anil Kumar was the only one that worked for me, as Developer mode was not showing and I did not want to use any 3rd party app either.

1. Unpair device
2. Tap on TRUST when the pop-up shows on the phone (if needed unplug and plug again the phone to the computer)
3. Kill settings app
4. Go to Settings -> Privacy & Security
   Developer mode will show this time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a newer Mac with Thunderbolt ports and are using a Thunderbolt Adapter to provide a USB port, you may have to reboot the adapter (i.e., unplug it from your Mac and plug it back in)! I upgraded my macOS to Ventura, my iOS to 16.5, Xcode to 14.3, etc., did all the things to get my phone to show up in Android Studio, and this is what finally got it working.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was plug in my iPhone 13 (This works with all Apple iPhones) into my MacBook Air (which Works with all MacBooks and iMacs), then open Xcode, and create a new project. Then on my iPhone, I opened settings, went to privacy and security, then scrolled down. Above the "Lockdown" button was developer mode. Then click it, enable it, then do the following prompts.

Comment: Do you mean "Cannot reproduce"? Or "Thanks for the solution"? If you try to provide a helpful answer, then why do you stress so much that this solution works only for you?

Comment: It looks like you have most of the necessary information in your answer but when describing navigating user interfaces a few select screenshots can help out a lot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Updating to Xcode 14 was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter it doesn't work sometimes. Just open the app with Xcode then run it on the physical device you may have to give a passcode and register your device.

Answer (score -1):

In iOS Version: 16.3.1

Please go to Settings => Privacy => Developer Mode.

If you do not see the option maybe is because you plug your cable when the iphone was locked.

Try this: unplug your cable, unlock your iphone, plug your cable again, you will see the option. The iphone will restart and when it turns on, a popup asking if you want to activate developer mode will show, accept and done.

Answer (score -1):

Developer mode doesn’t show on the device.
try these steps.
connect your iPhone with a Mac by Cable.
open Xcode chooses the device and signing certificate to register the device.
then go to mobile Security&policy and you will see the developer mode to make it active.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710066

> Turning on Developer Mode requires you to physically connect your device to a machine running Xcode. With a project open in Xcode 14 Beta 3, connect your phone and then navigate to Settings -> Privacy & Security, Developer Mode should appear now. If you've had that settings pane open before you connected your device, you may have to navigate back to Settings, and then go into Privacy & Security again.

In case you did not see this, for details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device

Note: iOS 16 RC available. It is worth updating.

Comment: Why are you mentioning that iOS 16 RC is available? iOS 16 has been out for nearly 8 months now.

Answer (score -3):

In iOS 16 (iPhone 14) your "Developer Mode" toggle button can really be hard to get to show up on your phone.  Like many above have answered, it's supposed to  show up under Settings-> Privacy & Security-> (scroll to bottom, almost the last entry) but doesn't bc Apple really doesn't seem to care about making basic stuff easy for developers, so try this:

Connect your iPhone to your Mac via a chord.
If you get a prompt to allow device, allow it.
Open XCode.
Click on the Product menu.
Select destination.
Click on your device name (it might already show a checkmark-- this is completely non-intuitive bc Apple is horrible)
Follow any prompts
Now when you go back you can see the developer mode and toggle it on.

[image]

Apple in iOS 16 decided to make it super-duper difficult to enable Developer Mode, which is supposed to show up on the iPhone under Settings->Privacy & Security.  No reason why this is the case, other than Apple can be pretty dim when it comes to trusting human beings.  What they COULD do is just use FingerID or FaceID to match developers to their Connect accounts, and make it really simple to toggle the button, INSTEAD OF HIDING IT WHICH IS TOTALLY INSANE ON APPLE'S PART!

You also might want to register your iPhone or mobile device with your Developer account (see 2nd picture).

[image]

Just wait until you find out how hard it is to find your Apple device's "Identifier" / Device ID / UDID.  I'll save you the trouble, it's just the device's serial number but with a dash inserted between the 8th and 9th digits.

Apple truly has issues when it comes to making life easy on its NEW YOUNG BUDDING developers, this much is certain. Maybe they like to keep it that way, to pad the salary levels at the top? (like Fraternity hazing)

Say thanks to Aashi Shrima here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/716697