# Developer mode required to open app from App Distribution, iOS 16

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

In react native every thing alright in android build. but when i try to install ios build in iphone its the popup come ''developer mode required''

[image]

Comment: i want install the app without the popup

Comment: So.. have you tried reading the message? You need to enable developer mode in able to install (local) builds to your device. Or distribute it normally through App Store.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device

Comment: ohh! THANK YOU .. now i understand  -epascarello and -nbokmans

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable developer mode in iOS 16.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733701/how-to-enable-developer-mode-in-ios-16-0)

Answer (score 5):

On the iPhone, go to Settings > Privacy & Security on the iOS device -> Developer Mode -> toggle the Developer mode on.

It will ask to restart the device, after restart the app will work.