# Developer mode required for installing

Tags: ios, xcode, diawi

I have an iOS app that is distributed via diawi.com. This has worked fine before, but now the iPad requires developer mode to install. I think I have found the solution here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733701/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-ios-16-0). But I have not found any reason why this is happening now. Is it something new Apple is doing? Is it any way for me to not having to enable developer mode when installing in the future?

Comment: In iOS 16 and later, ad-hoc signed builds require the device to be in developer mode.  This is to ensure that the user knows they are running code that has not been reviewed and signed by Apple.  To avoid this, don't use ad-hoc builds via diawi.  Use the App Store possibly with either custom app distribution or unlisted app distribution if your app isn't applicable for a general audience.